# Car Dealership says I have no credit history, but I do?

Tags: credit

My fiance and I went to Chrysler Dodge Jeep dealership to lease a car, nothing fancy just a Jeep under 30k. During an appointment we were told that I have absolutely no credit history, which is very strange as I have 6 credit cards since 2013 and 690 credit score report based on annualcreditreport.com. While, it's true that I never owned a car in the US before and did not have loans or mortgage, I always utilized credit cards. They recommended to contact credit bureau. I couldn't get trough to Experian but TransUnion said that they see no issues and it's dealership's system problem. However, the dealership keep saying that their hands are tied. I don't know what to do? I don't want to get a co-signer. Would you have any recommendations?

Comment: Have you tried other dealerships?  Either Jeep dealerships or dealerships in general.  If this issue is limited to the one dealership, and your heart isn't set on that specific Jeep, then this seems like *their problem,* not yours.

Comment: Is your credit history from outside of the US only? The way you phrase the statement 'I never owned a car in the US before' implies that your credit history might be from elsewhere. This can prevent your history from 'carrying over' into the US.

Comment: Just a side note in case this gets resolved but they see a different score: Dealerships may use a different scoring system. There is a FICO Auto Score which is affected by your history specifically with car loans. It shouldn't be a big difference, and likely Bacon's question is the correct path to investigate. Just be aware that with no auto loan history, your 690 might be a lower value for a dealership.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I read that as having had credit cards in the US.

Comment: Anastasia: If they're finding "_absolutely no credit history_" instead of "_just not a good-enough history_", have you double-checked that the dealership are using your correct details? Have you ever varied the name you use? As in... someone's official name might be "Fred Arthur Bloggs" but prefer to be known as "Arthur" in everyday life. If they forget and enter their name as "Arthur Bloggs" on some documents, that _might_ not get linked to "Fred Arthur Bloggs".

Answer (score 2):

> 690 credit score report based on annualcreditreport.com

AnnualCreditReport.com itself does not provide or entitle you to credit scores. Did you purchase your FICO score from one of the bureaus while obtaining your reports? What did the reports themselves show?

> TransUnion said that they see no issues

Does this mean you do have data in your TransUnion credit report, including the expected 6 credit cards? Note that a given lender may pull your report from only one bureau and it may not be TransUnion. Did the dealership say which bureau(s) they used? Did you get the corresponding report from AnnualCreditReport.com?